# Are the generators of the ring $R[x]$ the same as the generators of $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noetherian

Here's why I think this:

Let $R=\langle a_1,\dots,a_m\rangle$ (I'm assuming $R$ is finitely generated because that's all I'm concerned with), then each element of $R[x]$ can be written as
$$(r_{1,0}a_1+r_{2,0}a_2+\cdots+r_{m,0}a_m)+(r_{1,1}a_1+r_{2,1}a_2+\cdots+r_{m,1}a_m)x+\cdots+(r_{1,n}a_1+r_{2,n}a_2+\cdots+r_{m,n}a_m)x^n$$
$$=(r_{1,0}+r_{1,1}x+\cdots+r_{1,n}x^n)a_1+(r_{2,0}+r_{2,1}x+\cdots+r_{2,n}x^n)a_2+\cdots+(r_{m,0}+r_{m,1}x+\cdots+r_{m,n}x^n)a_m,$$
which is a sum of elements of $\{a_1,\dots,a_m\}$ with coefficients in $R[x]$, so $R[x]=\langle a_1,\dots,a_m\rangle$.

Here's why I think this is wrong:

It trivially implies the Hilbert basis theorem, which can't be that easy to prove.

Comment: So how would you generate $x$ using the $a_i$?

Comment: @Riquelme my understanding of the ideal generated by $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_m$ in $R[x]$ is that it is the set of elements that can be written as $c_1a_1+c_2a_2+\cdots+c_ma_m$, where the coefficients $c_1,c_2,\dots,c_m$ are allowed to be any elements of $R[x]$, so I would generate $x$ by creating $1_R$ using the generators of $R$, and then use $x$ as the coefficient. That is, I would write $x(c_1a_1+\cdots+c_ma_m)$ where $c_1a_1+\cdots+c_ma_m=1_R$

Comment: You talk about generators of the *ring* in the title, but based on that comment and the reference to the Hilbert basis theorem it sounds like you really want to ask about generators of an *ideal*. These are very different! So what ideal do you want to generate, over what ring?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Okay, I think I was just confused about the difference between the generators of a ring and the generators of an ideal in the ring.